# When to use getStaticProps and getServerSideProps in real world scenario

Tags: next.js

Hello I am new to the Next.js, I know that in getStaticProps Next.js will pre-render this page at build time and in getServerSideProps Next.js will pre-render this page on each request using the data returned by getServerSideProps

But i want a example of when to use getStaticProps and getServerSideProps for website

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With **getServerSideProps (SSR)** data is fetched at request time, so your page will have a higher Time to first byte (TTFB), but will always pre-render pages with fresh data.(can be use for dynamic content/it allows you to improve your SEO as in this method the data is rendered before it reaches the client.)

With **Static Generation (SSG)** The HTML is generated at build time and will be reused on each request, TTFB is slower and the page is usually faster, but you need to rebuild your app every time the data is updated (can be acceptable for a blog, but not for an e-commerce).

With **Incremental Static Regeneration (ISG)** static content can also be dynamic, the page will be rebuilt in the background with an interval-based HTTP request. You can specify how often pages are updated with a revalidate key inside getStaticProps, this works great with fallback : true and allows you to have (almost) always updated content.

When to use:

1. **getStaticProps:** Any data that changes infrequently, particularly from a CMS. (Must be used with getStaticPaths if there's a dynamic route).
2. **revalidate:** An easy add-on to getStaticProps if the data might change, and we're OK serving a cached version.
3. **getServerSideProps:** Primarily useful with data that must be fetched on the server that changes frequently or depends on user authentication.When we want to fetch data that relates to the user's cookies/activity and is consequently not possible to cache.

Answer (score 3):

**SSR** doesn’t cache any data. It fetches new data on every request which often results in a slower performance.
**SSR** should be used when we don't know what the user wants, otherwise we use **SSG** or **ISG** in case of dynamic content.
Here is some examples to what to use in each case:

**getServerSideProps (SSR)**:

- a JWT after a successful login
- GeoLocation of the user (the content on the page may depend on the geo location of the client, so it's very useful to use SSR in this case)

**Static Generation (SSG)**:

- wiki page
- Privacy-policy page
- a blog if data is not changed very often
- Website settings (Colors, themes, ...)

**Incremental Static Regeneration (ISG)**:

- e-commerce store
- news website
- The data revalidation will happen on the server and will benefit all
  visitors.

**Client-side rendering (CSR)**:

- Content that is only accessible for authenticated users (dashboards)
- The data revalidation will happen on the client and will only benefit that single user.

**SWR/ReactQuery + Incremental Static Regeneration (SWR + ISG)**:

- this approach is also a very good one if you want instantly updated data for the current user and statically regenerated for the next visitors.

NextJs v12.2.0 introduced the "**On-Demand Revalidation**" which is very powerful and useful.Let's say you have a news website, using the old Incremental Static Regeneration is not the best solution, imagine we set the revalidation to 1 hour, that means the newest urgent news that we just published will not be published on the website until one hour, too bad :( and here where **On-Demand Revalidation** comes to play. When you publish your new article you will call the "revalidate()" method using an API and the articles page will be regenrated without waiting the revalidation time.

Comment: Thank for you actually sharing a list of real use-cases. One question though, for SSG, did you mean, "a blog if data is NOT changed very often"?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, if you have a blog on which the content is changed very often then it's better to choose ISR. It's just a mistake from me, but I fixed.Thanks for sharing